# How to explain to someone that a data structure should not draw itself, explaining separation of concerns?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, extend, separation-of-concerns, extends

I have another programmer who I'm trying to explain why it is that a UI component should not also be a data-structure.

For instance say that you get a data-structure that contains a record-set from the "database", and you wish to display that record-set in a UI component within your application.

According to this programmer (who will remain nameless, he's young and I'm teaching him...), we should subclass the data-structure into a class that will draw the UI component within our application!!!!!!

And thus according to this logic, the record-set should manage the drawing of the UI.

******Head Desk*****

I know that asking a record-set to draw itself is wrong, because, if you wish to render the same data-structure on more than one type of component on your UI, you are going to have a real mess on your hands; you'll need to extend yet another class for each and every UI component that you render from the base-class of your record-set;

I am well aware of the "cleanliness" of the of the MVC pattern (and by that what I really mean is you don't confuse your data (the Model) with your UI (the view) or the actions that take place on the data (the Controller more or less...okay not really the API should really handle that...and the Controller should just make as few calls to it as it can, telling it which view to render))  But it's certainly alot cleaner than using data-structures to render UI components!

Is there any other advice I could send his way other than the example above?  I understand that when you first learn OOP you go through "a stage" where you where just want to extend everything.

Followed by a stage when you think that Design Patterns are the solution every single problem...which isn't entirely correct either...[thanks Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/09/head-first-design-patterns.html).

Is there a way that I can gently nudge this kid in the right direction?  Do you have any more examples that might help explain my point to him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you heard of Martin Fowler?

[Separating User Interface
Code](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/separation.pdf)

Anyway, if he wants to go further in that direction of adding render methods to his data controls, have him look at "loose coupling". It's okay to create some generic type of interface that gets him halfway there, but the UI component should take it the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to functional vs. non-functional responsibilities. What the data structure does and how it's visualized are two completely separate things -- essentially the root of the MVC pattern.

There's also a notion of circular dependencies here. Since the UI must know about the data structures, if you allow the data structures to then depend on the UI, you've got yourself a nice little ball of mud.

Comment: And by functional you mean interacting with the data with the UI, and non-functional being; just a container for the data, like the result-set...right?

Comment: Functional as in "what something does", non-functional as in "how something looks". In MVC, the "what something does" is the Model, and "how something looks" is the visualization of the model, the View.

Answer (score 0):

Generally on the point of decoupling:

1. Not only can there be different components of the UI rendering the same data structure. You may even have completely different UIs (Web, Desktop Application, ...) Now of course, you could subclass `Person` with `WebPerson` and `DesktopPerson` *(this already sounds wrong, doesn't it? The naming is simply not about the kind of Person - it's about something else)*.
2. Each UI could work on different kinds of Persons, e.g. `Teacher` and `Student`. So we get `WebPerson`, `WebTeacher`, `WebStudent`, `DesktopPerson`, `DesktopTeacher` and `DesktopStudent`.

Now let's say, `WebPerson` defines the method "drawAddressFields()" to draw a web version of the address fields. But since `WebTeacher` has to derive from `Teacher` to use the additional data field "salary" (and let's assume single inheritance), it must implement "drawAddressFields()" once again!

So maybe the argument of "this will cause much more work" will help to create some motivation :-)

*BTW, it will automatically lead to creating some delegate that implements the code of drawAddressField(), which will then evolve to creating a component that does the drawing separately from the data structure.*